# If $PAP^{-1} = B$, does there exist $Q$ with positive determinant such that $QAQ^{-1} = B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology

Suppose $A,B$ are conjugate real $n \times n$-matrices with $B = PAP^{-1}$ for some real matrix $P$. Does there exist a real matrix $Q$ with positive determinant such that $B = QAQ^{-1}$? 
The answer to the question is obviously yes if $n$ is odd since we can just take $Q = -P$. What about even $n$?

---

I asked this question because I wanted to show that the conjugacy classes of real matrices are path-connected (which is [not true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3420882/are-all-conjugacy-classes-in-textgl-n-mathbb-r-path-connected), as it turns out) and I had reduced the problem down to the above question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

A counterexample for $n = 2$ is $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = -A$. Then, the only $2\times 2$-matrices $P$ that satisfy $PA = BP$ are those of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & -a \end{pmatrix}$. Obviously, if such a matrix $P$ has real entries, then its determinant is $\leq 0$.

Comment: This answer makes me sad. Thank you anyways. You saved me a lot of hours.